# simplify pandas dataframe creation with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I tried to simplify some expressions I created in Jupyter lab.
Sorry for my bad written text, this is my first post here, so I am very new.

This is the original code and it is working:

```
count = pd.DataFrame(columns=["wordcount", "totalwords", "lang", "person"])

x = alle[alle['word'].str.contains('merkel')]
count.loc["all_merkel"]= x["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['all_merkel', 'totalwords'] = alle["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['all_merkel', 'lang'] = "alle"
count.at['all_merkel', 'person'] = "merkel"

x = de[de['word'].str.contains('merkel')]
count.loc["de_merkel"]= x["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['de_merkel', 'totalwords'] = de["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['de_merkel', 'lang'] = "de"
count.at['de_merkel', 'person'] = "merkel"

x = en[en['word'].str.contains('merkel')]
count.loc["en_merkel"]= x["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['en_merkel', 'totalwords'] = en["count"].sum(axis=0)
count.at['en_merkel', 'lang'] = "en"
count.at['en_merkel', 'person'] = "merkel"
```

The result is this tiny data frame:

```
         wordcount  totalwords  lang    person
all_merkel  2520    3879156     alle    merkel
de_merkel   2119    3138899     de      merkel
en_merkel   196      427309     en      merkel
```

Now, I wanted to make this code a little bit smaller but I am not able to.
This was my best try, but it is not working.

```
pdlist = [alle, de, en]

for i in pdlist:
    x = i[i['word'].str.contains('merkel')]
    count.loc[i]= x["count"].sum(axis=0)
    count.at[i, ['totalwords']] = data["count"].sum(axis=0)
    count.at[i, ['lang']] = "alle"
    count.at[i, ['person']] = "merkel"
```

"alle", "de", and "en" are also data frames with a column "count" that contains integers that were summed. Also, I count all integers in the "count" column, if the "word" column contains a certain word. in this case "merkel"

If you need further information, I can hopefully provide it.

Comment: Can you please provide a small input dataframe then desired output?  See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you can use a dictionary (`pddict`) instead of a list to store the dataframes so that you can associate the prefixes (`all`, `de`, `en`) with their dataframes (`df = pddict[key]`). With the dictionary `pddict`, you can iterate through each key and derive the key values (`all_merkel`, `en_merkel`, etc.) by appending the `key` with `_merkel`. Let me know if encounter any issues

```
pddict = {
    'all': alle,
    'de': de,
    'en': en
}

for key in pddict:
    df = pddict[key]
    key_string = key + '_merkel'
    x = df[df['word'].str.contains('merkel')]
    count.loc[key_string]= x["count"].sum(axis=0)
    count.at[key_string, 'totalwords'] = df["count"].sum(axis=0)
    # Only alle have its prefix (all) different from the value assign here (alle)
    count.at[key_string, 'lang'] = key if key != 'all' else 'alle'
    count.at[key_string, 'person'] = "merkel"
```